# How do I use shadows and lighting to project two seperate textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shadows

So I'm making a scene that uses two different textures, one for lit areas and one for dark areas. I was wondering how I could set up a node system in cycles to display lit areas with one texture, and dark areas with another, all in real-time. (< Or baked? I'm not super sure on how/what baking works/is.)

Edit:

So what I'm going for is something like this:

[image]

Where the fresnel separates my two textures, but instead of fresnel I want to use a light source to determine what should be light and what should be dark.

Here is my simple node setup. As you can see, what I'm looking for is something else to plug into the 'fac' of my mix shader

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! Try to explain what you currently do to set, eg, at least one of those textures in your node setup (maybe add a screenshot of the node setup, and/or a simple test scene), it would help others to understand what you're doing and what you need, perhaps.